# Align HTML buttons in a row in Flask Forms

Tags: html, css, flask

I have a Flask form:

```
<form action="/data1" method="GET">
    <button type="submit">Feed1</button>
</form>

<form action="/data2" method="GET">
    <button type="submit">Feed2</button>
</form>
```

Button is displayed as below:

[image]

Expectation is to add the buttons in a same row.

I tried below style, but it's not helping:

```
button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Not sure if it's because of Form tag, it is not getting aligned. I have tried wrapper class as well, but no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. Set the `display` property of your buttons to `inline-flex` and your class `row` with a `display` of `flex`.  Here is a working snippet of what you need to do.

```css
button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.row{
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<form action="/data1" method="GET">
    <button type="submit">Feed1</button>
</form>

<form action="/data2" method="GET">
    <button type="submit">Feed2</button>
</form>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can align the buttons in a row using CSS flexbox. Just add a parent container with the `display: flex` property, and set `justify-content: center` to center the buttons horizontally.

#### Example:

HTML:

```html
<div class="button-row">
  <form action="/data1" method="GET">
    <button type="submit">Feed1</button>
  </form>
  <form action="/data2" method="GET">
    <button type="submit">Feed2</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.button-row {
display: flex; /* set the display property to flex */
justify-content: center; /* horizontally center the buttons */
}

button {
background-color: #4CAF50;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 5px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 0 10px; /* add 10px margin to the buttons */
}
```

Hope it helps :)